# CallBack url for social authemtication using ngCordovaOauth

Tags: cordova-plugins

If i am using ngCordovaOauth for authentication for Facebook,Twitter and Instagram 
then what should be callback url, when developing and app for mobile .

Answer (score 0):

If you read the plugin docs

> Using ngCordovaOauth In Your Project
>
> Each web service API acts independently in this library. However, when
>   configuring each web service, one thing must remain consistent. You
>   must use http://localhost/callback as your callback / redirect URI.
>   This is because this library will perform tasks when this URL is
>   found.

So, the callback url is `http://localhost/callback`